# How to get the random file path for iOS TestRunner or TestBundle in KMM?

Tags: ios, testing, io, kotlin-multiplatform

For UI test in Xcode I could read a file under UITest bundle like this.

```
    func testReadFile() throws {
        // Get Bundle for UI test target
        let testBundle = Bundle(for: XCTestBase.self)
        
        // Find the file belongs to current test runner.
        if let filePath = testBundle.url(forResource: "good", withExtension: "txt") {
          print(filePath)
        }
    }
```

And with PO, I know it will use the iosAppUITests-Runner instance as the path for file `good.txt`. So that is a random path only for runtime use.

```
(lldb) po testBundle.url(forResource: "good", withExtension: "txt")
▿ Optional<URL>
  ▿ some : file:///Users/haibozhou/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EFF818A9-6670-4635-9618-DEBFB2C15156/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA9E0623-D0DF-414C-A831-5654BBB64AF8/iosAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/iosAppUITests.xctest/good.txt
    - _url : file:///Users/haibozhou/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EFF818A9-6670-4635-9618-DEBFB2C15156/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA9E0623-D0DF-414C-A831-5654BBB64AF8/iosAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/iosAppUITests.xctest/good.txt
```

In KMM, I want to implement the same for iOS. However I got a problem. It seems the test class(XCTestBase) is not resolved for KMM project. Because it is not exposed to KMM project I guess.

```
val testBundle = NSBundle.bundleForClass(XCTestBase)
```

After I try things like this with a relative path, still without luck. Thus, what is the correct way to find the file path from Kotlin iOS code for iOS test runner?

```
actual fun readFile(path: String): String {
    val string = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(
        "../iosAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/iosAppUITests.xctest/good.txt",
        NSUTF8StringEncoding, null) ?: return "File not found!"
    // ignored code...
    return string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I figure out how to do it today.

Basically, first get all Bundles then filter out the test bundle, in my case it named `iosAppUITests.xctest`, replace it with your test target name in your project. Now we have the test bundle finally! We could get the dictionary from this testBundle and key-values after. And because KMM is interops with iOS by Objective-C framework but not Swift framework, we need do it with Objective-C format.

Well, it is a workaround for now.

```
actual fun getEnv(key: String): String {
    // Get all bundles
    val allBundles = NSBundle.allBundles
    val bundles = allBundles.filterIsInstance<NSBundle>()
        .apply { if (size != allBundles.size) return "null" }
    // Filter out bundle for xctest, which is the current test runner test bundle.
    val testBundle: NSBundle = bundles.first {
        it.isLoaded() &&
        it.bundleURL.lastPathComponent == "iosAppUITests.xctest"
    }

    // Get the dict, in KMM it is Map<*,*>
    val path = testBundle.pathForResource("fileName", "plist")
    val dict = path?.let { NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile(it) }
    println("~ dict: $dict")

    return dict?.get(key) as String
}
```